# TypeError('The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object....) though I am providing it a numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

I am providing to my feed_dict a numpy array but it still gives this error that the feed need to be a tf.Tensor object.

```
index = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='index')
dontknow = np.random.choice(range(1,200), 180)
_, summary = sess.run([train, merged], feed_dict={
            input_placeholder:train_batch_x,
            attr_placeholder:train_class_attr,
            label_placeholder:train_batch_y,
            index:dontknow
            })
```

Is this a bug in the tensorflow library since I wanted to post as an issue but wasn't sure. Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is not with `dontknow` variable, it is with one of these:

```
input_placeholder:train_batch_x,
attr_placeholder:train_class_attr,
label_placeholder:train_batch_y,
```

When I remove them, I can execute your stuff without any error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

index = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='index')
dontknow = np.random.choice(range(1,200), 180)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(index, {index:dontknow})
```

Print each of them before doing your `sess.run` to find which one is the tensor

Comment: Thanks Salvador.. I found my mistake.It was another variable which was a tensor.